# Scala Dynamic Instantiation. How to pass in parameter that must extend certain trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, manifest, traits

I'm learning scala and created a foo bar code to play around with traits and Manifest. Here's the usage I'm aiming for:

```
slang = new Slang()
slang.speak[MilitarySlang]("Private")
slang.speak[GanstaSlang]("Homie")
```

Here's my code:

```
trait Foo {
  val foo = "Foo'd Up "
  trait Style {
    def phrase(subject : String): String
  }
  def speak(someone: String): String
}

class Slang extends Foo {

  class MilitarySlang extends Style {
    def phrase(subject: String) = "Beyond All Recognition, " + subject
  }

  class GanstaSlang extends Style {
    def phrase(subject: String) = "Fo Sheezy, " + subject
  }

  def speak[Foo with Style: Manifest](someone: String): String = { 
    val mbar = manifest[Foo with Style].erasure.newInstance().asInstanceOf[Foo with Style]
    foo + mbar.phrase(someone)
  }
}
```

Current error I get is with `speak[Foo *with Style]` Error ']' expected but 'with' found.

**How do I ensure that the type inferred with a class that MUST EXTEND Foo with Style?**

Comment: But Foo is abstract, and its instance cant be created even by using the manifest route.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to work ...

```
slang = new Slang()
slang.speak[MilitarySlang]("Private")
```

... 1st because you've defined `speak()` to take no arguments, and 2nd because `MilitarySlang` isn't in scope (i.e. not visible from the call site).

One simple solution (perhaps overly simple) is to move `Style` from a type parameter to a value parameter.

Inside `Foo` the definition becomes `def speak(style: Style, subject: String): String`, and inside `Slang` you'd have ...

```
def speak(style: Style, subject: String): String =
  foo + style.phrase(subject)
```

... which can be invoked like so ...

```
val slang = new Slang
slang.speak(new slang.MilitarySlang, "private")
// res0: String = Foo'd Up Beyond All Recognition, private
```

Comment: Well, you're trying to communicate, from the call site to the `Slang` instance, which `Style` to use. It might appear a bit cleaner if there were a default `Style`, so you only specify non-default styles, or you could hide the `Style` parameter in an implicit, which would make things look very clean but it obscures the inner workings of the code. Perhaps someone else has a better way to get that information (`Style`) communicated.

Answer (score 1):

You might split Style into a separate trait but use a self type in Foo like this.

```
trait Style {
  def phrase(subject : String): String
}

trait Foo {
  this: Style =>
  val foo = "Foo'd Up "
  def speak(): String
}
```

This will tell the compiler that anything that extends Foo must extend it with Style.

Comment: Thanks Scott, while I knew about Scala's self type reference to enforce one or more mixins, that would fail my usage criteria. I'd have to declare a Slang for each Style which is a waste of memory if `foo` was memory intensive and not just a simple string.